# Lotus notes Subtract collection from another collection not working

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Please could anyone help me 
In Lotus notes Subtract collection from another collection not working.
both dc1 and dc2 collection count is working but not able to subtract dc1 from dc2

It is giving

> Error 4336 invalid object type for method argument At line : Call
>   dc2.Subtract(dc1)

Please find the code:

```
Sub sendNotificationAppOwnerMerged(coll As NotesDocumentCollection)

    On Error GoTo errorhandler  
    Dim sess As NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim dc1 As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim dc2 As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim query As String

    If coll.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Set dc2= coll.Clone()

    Set doc = dc2.GetFirstDocument
    While Not doc Is Nothing    
        Set doc = dc2.GetFirstDocument
        query = | Field SATTEAMNAME = "| & doc.SATTeamName(0) & |"|
        Set dc1= dc2.Clone()    
        Call dc1.Ftsearch(query, 0)
        MsgBox dc2.count
        MsgBox dc1.count
        ' send email to all apps in dc1
        MsgBox "Mail Sent to " + doc.SATTeam(0)

        Call dc2.Subtract(dc1)

        If dc2.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Wend

    Exit Sub
errorhandler:   
    MessageBox "Error" & Str(Err) & ": " & Error$   & "On Line " & cstr(Erl)
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a memory that says that a NotesDocumentCollection returned by the FTSearch method is ordered, and it's actually a different type of collection than a NotesDocumentCollection returned by other methods. I suspect that the error is trying to tell you that you can't do the subtraction of an ordered FT collection from an unordered collection. I've made this a comment rather than an answer because this memory is from a very long time ago.

Comment: I concur. Furthermore, Subtract is (or maybe was)  s l o w . . . Better write the subtract yourself, using NotesDocumentCollection.DeleteDocument(). Or in your case, if you want to find the number of teams with a different name, use *query = | ! Field SATTEAMNAME = "| & doc.SATTeamName(0) & |"|*

Answer (score 1):

The collection to subtract must be in the collection being subtracted.

Try:

```
Sub sendNotificationAppOwnerMerged(coll As NotesDocumentCollection)
    On Error GoTo errorhandler  
    Dim sess As NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim dc1 As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim dc2 As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim query As String

    If coll.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set dc1= coll.Clone()

    Set doc = dc1.GetFirstDocument
    While Not doc Is Nothing    
        query = | Field SATTEAMNAME = "| & doc.SATTeamName(0) & |"|
        Set dc2= dc1.Clone()
        Call dc2.Ftsearch(query, 0)
        MsgBox dc2.count
        MsgBox dc1.count
        ' send email to all apps in dc1
        MsgBox "Mail Sent to " + doc.SATTeam(0)

        Call dc1.Subtract(dc2)

        If dc1.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set doc = dc1.GetFirstDocument
    Wend

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Although there is a potential for infinite loop if the first doc in dc1 is never subtracted from the dc1 collection.  There is probably a better way to do this.  Does the error occur on the first attempt or afterwards?  Continually subtracting from dc1 and then re-cloning dc2 may also be causing errors.

Comment: thanks for reply. it happens at first attempt itself  at line "Call dc1.Subtract(dc2)". I would like the Subtract method work. Any other way is also helpful.